# Finding all elements of a string vector that end with a given string in R

Tags: regex, r

Suppose I have a character vector:

```
test <- c("a##", "b", "c##", "d", "e")
```

I want to retrieve the indexes of elements ending with "##".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one method using grep:

```
grep("##$", test)
```

This returns indices 1 and 3 as a vector.  The "##$" is a regular expression that says match if ## are the last two characters, the "$". anchors the ## to the end.